Azure DevOps access and permission management with Entra ID
I created an ADO organization (ex:https://dev.azure.com/ABC). Configured with Entra ID to to manage access level using below AD groups and it working fine.

AzureDevOps Access Level Stakeholder
AzureDevOps Access Level Basic
AzureDevOps Access Level Basic and test plan

My question is still I am unable to figure out, how can I add the users who has Visual Studio licenses (Enterprise, Pro and MSDN)? Currently, I am giving direct access to uses who have VS license. These VS license also managing by security groups.

Should I add VS license holders directly to ADO?
Should I add them to Basic license group too?
Is there any other way?

really appreciate any response.

You can treat users with a VS subscription just like any other user. According to the official doc Supported access levels,

For users who already have a Visual Studio subscription. The system automatically recognizes the user's subscription—Visual Studio Enterprise, Visual Studio Professional, Visual Studio Test Professional, or MSDN Platform—and enables any other features that are included in their subscription level. If you assign Basic or Stakeholder, they also receive their Visual Studio subscription benefits upon sign-in.

If you want you can also create an "AzureDevOps Access Level VS Subscriber" group for users with VS subscription. But this group is only used to specifically manage users with VS subscriptions, not to assign access levels. Their access level will be automatically recognized as Visual Studio Subscriber.

Thank you Ziyang for the explanation. Really appreciate it.
